# How to proceed to the next video in youtube playlist using python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, youtube, youtube-api

I tried using this code:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name("ytp-next-button ytp-button")
elem.click()
```

but without mouse on the video there is no toolBar.
what can I do?

Comment: Did your script hover mouse on the player yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are unable to click on that button not because you need to put cursor on it, but because of wrong locator: to use `find_element_by_class_name()` name should not contain spaces... But there is a space in your case. So you should use `find_element_by_xpath()` instead. Try following code:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="ytp-next-button ytp-button"]')
elem.click()
```